# Solving $1=\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}, 2t \right)$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

Is it possible to solve the following equation that contain the incomplete Gamma function?

$$1=\Gamma\left(\dfrac{d}{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(\dfrac{d}{2}, 2t \right)$$

I would like to find the value of $d$, but I do not know if there is a way.

$t$ can take any positive value.

Comment: Am I correct to interpret this as you would like to know for which $d$ the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(d/2,2t) = \int_0^{2t} s^{-d/2-1}e^{-s}ds = 1$? What to you mean for when $t\to\infty$? Then you are left with $\Gamma(d/2) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, finally I could compute when $t$ goes to infinity, where $d$ is either 2 or 4. The problem is when I say for any $t$. Perhaps I should edit the question.